# SQS Messages that are longer triggering lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have a lambda that is triggered by an SQS but I want to disable the event trigger in the lower environments.

If there are other parts that publishes to that SQS, what would happens to the the message? There is no DLQ on the SQS.  Will the message disappear after the MessageRetentionPeriod is up?

Comment: Is your question effectively: "if nothing consumes messages from my SQS queue, what happens to the messages in that queue?"

Comment: @jarmod pretty much

Comment: Per the [FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/faqs/): Once the message retention quota is reached, your messages are automatically deleted. 'Quota' is a bad choice of word there imo, but it's referring to the message retention period.

Comment: @jarmod that is what I am trying to confirm. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the SQS [FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/faqs/):

> Q: How long can I keep my messages in Amazon SQS message queues?
> A: You can configure the Amazon SQS message retention period to a value from 1 minute to 14 days. The default is 4 days. Once the message retention quota is reached, your messages are
> automatically deleted.

The word 'quota' is a bad choice, imo, but it means the message retention period.

Note: if a message happens to have been moved from a regular SQS queue to its associated Dead Letter Queue then the retention period is considered to start when the message first arrived on the underlying SQS queue, not when it was transferred to the DLQ.